# Linking Magento 2.3.2 to an SQL DB?

Tags: upgrade, sql, server-setup, pricing

Hoping for some help - its my first post here!

I am looking to link my newly created Magento website (using v2.3.2) to an Microsoft SQL server database.I would like to Database connection with Microsoft SQL server.

Would anyone be able to recommend the best way to go around this? Not sure if this is something Magento supports directly or would have to be done through plugins or addons ?

Just looking for some early advice on this as i am a bit stuck.

I am wanting the website to run a night time job to pick up new prices, descriptions and/or stock etc.

Thanks
John